# Remove dot after journal volume using numeric-comp style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, punctuation

I am trying to remove the dot after the volume field for articles in my bibliography. I haven't managed to find a solution that works yet. I suspect I need to redefined `setunit` using `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}` but I haven't managed to make it work yet. Does anybody have any ideas what I would have to do to remove the dot?

The MWE looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber,isbn=false,date=year,url=false]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{
    \iffieldundef{pages}{}{\clearfield{doi}}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcomma\space}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Debnath2013,
author = {Debnath, Mainak and Dutta, Arpan and Biswas, Surajit and Das, Kalyan Kumar and Lee, Hon Man and V{\'{i}}cha, Jan and Marek, Radek and Marek, Jaromir and Ali, Mahammad},
doi = {10.1016/j.poly.2013.07.013},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/pmj27/Mendeley/Library/Debnath et al. - 2013 - Catalytic oxidation of aromatic hydrocarbons by mono-oxido-alkoxidovanadium(V) complexes of ONNO donor ethylened.pdf:pdf},
issn = {02775387},
journal = {Polyhedron},
keywords = {benzoic acid,ethylenediamine- bis,phenolate,terpenes,toluene},
mendeley-tags = {benzoic acid,terpenes,toluene},
month = {oct},
number = {2},
pages = {189--198},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{Catalytic oxidation of aromatic hydrocarbons by mono-oxido-alkoxidovanadium(V) complexes of ONNO donor ethylenediamine-bis(phenolate) ligands}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S027753871300538X},
volume = {63},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\cite{Debnath2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The result I get with your code is "_Polyhedron_ 63 (2013) 189–198." No dot.

Comment: My mistake. Please try again. The MWE had no "number" field.

Comment: Do not remove fields by making their field format empty: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{}`. This is bound to confuse and upset biblatex's punctuation tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The added dot is hardcoded in `volume+number+eid` macro, of `standard.bbx`. Once you want to remove the journal number (which this macro expects), you could redefine it, instead of using `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{}`. With:

```
\renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
```

As far as I know, this macro is only used by the `article` driver in `numeric-comp`, but I'm not absolutely sure of this, so some attention for undesired effects is due. [See edit below]

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber,isbn=false,date=year,url=false]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{
    \iffieldundef{pages}{}{\clearfield{doi}}
}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{}
\renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcomma\space}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Debnath2013,
        author = {Debnath, Mainak and Dutta, Arpan and Biswas, Surajit and Das, Kalyan Kumar and Lee, Hon Man and V{\'{i}}cha, Jan and Marek, Radek and Marek, Jaromir and Ali, Mahammad},
        doi = {10.1016/j.poly.2013.07.013},
        file = {:D$\backslash$:/pmj27/Mendeley/Library/Debnath et al. - 2013 - Catalytic oxidation of aromatic hydrocarbons by mono-oxido-alkoxidovanadium(V) complexes of ONNO donor ethylened.pdf:pdf},
        issn = {02775387},
        journal = {Polyhedron},
        keywords = {benzoic acid,ethylenediamine- bis,phenolate,terpenes,toluene},
        mendeley-tags = {benzoic acid,terpenes,toluene},
        month = {oct},
        number = {2},
        pages = {189--198},
        publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
        title = {{Catalytic oxidation of aromatic hydrocarbons by mono-oxido-alkoxidovanadium(V) complexes of ONNO donor ethylenediamine-bis(phenolate) ligands}},
        url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S027753871300538X},
        volume = {63},
        year = {2013}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

    \cite{Debnath2013}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

**Edit**: You can make the change conditional on the entrytype, to play on the safe side, with:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{%
        \renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
            \printfield{volume}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \printfield{eid}}%
        }%
        {}%
    }
```

**Edit 2**: moewe confirms in the comments that, in the standard styles, `volume+number+eid` is indeed used only by the `article` entrytype. So, in this context, it is perfectly safe to go with the initially proposed solution.

Comment: Works excellently and the `\AtEveryBibitem` idea was very useful!

Comment: @P-M, I must add a comment. Though this works, I don't really think that it is a good idea to remove the information on the number of the journal. Not every journal has a continuous page numbering throughout the volume, and this can result in insufficiently specified references.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you, these are the guidelines I have been given though.

Comment: The code from the edit should be unnecessary. With the standard styles `volume+number+eid` is only used in `@article`, so the `\ifentrytype{article}` adds no protection. Since the macro will not occur in citations (unless `\fullcite`) is used, there is no need for `\AtEveryBibitem`.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe! As far as I had checked, I thought so, but it is somewhat hard to be sure sometimes. I'll edit the question to add the info.

Comment: Note that both the `\AtEveryBibitem`s in your answer could introduce spurious spaces. Some line ends need `%` 'protection'.

Comment: @moewe, I had missed that! Corrected.

Comment: Another way would be to get rid of the `number` field in `\AtEveryBibitem` (as is already done for the DOI) `\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{pages}{}{\clearfield{doi}}\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{number}}{}}`

Comment: @moewe, that's a neat idea. And more robust than mine, I'd say. I won't be troubled at all, on the contrary, if you care to give it as an answer.

Comment: In a way I prefer your solution. But I have added the alternative anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative solution that clears the `number` field in `\AtEveryBibitem` similarly to how you handle the DOI already

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {}
    {\clearfield{doi}}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{number}}
    {}}
```

You won't have to redefine a macro that way, but you hook into every bibitem. If you use `\fullcite` anywhere you will need the same for `\AtEveryCitekey`

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {}
    {\clearfield{doi}}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{number}}
    {}}
```